# Flutter - how to avoid reloading Google Maps between routes?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-state

I have Google Maps on several routes of my app. Would there be away to avoid reloading the Google Map on a new route?
I was thinking of doing away with routes, and using a big Stack, with Google Maps on the bottom, and just switching on and off various widgets, but setting state for Google Maps (eg adding markers) becomes difficult from widgets down the stack...

Comment: Try give map widget a global key.